# How to do async filters in python-telegram-bot?

Tags: python-asyncio, python-telegram-bot

How can I `await` in `def filter` ? In my case I need to fetch some data from database: filter checks if user has role X.

It seems like I cannot do `await` in filter function. If I make `async def filter` I get coroutine instead of boolean as result of `filter()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's right, filters are not intended to perform any I/O logic. In general, [`BaseHandler.check_update`](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.ext.basehandler.html#telegram.ext.BaseHandler.check_update) is intended to make the decision soleley based on the `update` and at most some internal state.
I recommend to move your asyncio logic into the handler callback and do some `if-then-else` right there.

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of the `python-telegram-bot` library.

Comment: _based on the `update` and at most some internal state._ That's what I need to know. Currently I bypass it with `yield` keyword.